# Problem adding in trace to Plotly figure that was converted from Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, plotly

I am trying to add in a new scatter trace based on the instructions on this web page: `https://plot.ly/matplotlib/modifying-a-matplotlib-figure/`

However, when I try to run the following code:

`plotly_fig['data'].append( dict(x=x, y=logx, type='scatter', mode='lines') )`

I receive the following error:

`plotly_fig['data'].append( dict(x=x, y=logx, type='scatter', mode='lines') )`
`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'`

So far I have tried:

1.) `plotly_fig.update(data=dict(x=x, y=logx, type='scatter', mode='lines'))`

which doesn't seem to do anything.

2.) `plotly_fig.add_scatter(name= "test", mode='lines', xaxis='x', yaxis='y',x=x.tolist(), y=sinx.tolist(), line= {'color': 'rgba (31, 119, 180, 1)', 'dash': 'solid', 'width': 1.5})`

which seems to add in the trace but when I run:

`py.plot(plotly_fig, filename='test.html')`

the new trace doesn't plot.

3.) `new_trace = dict(type='scatter', x=x, y=sinx, mode='lines', line= {'color': 'rgba (31, 119, 180, 1)', 'dash': 'solid', 'width': 1.5})`

`plotly_fig.append_trace(new_trace, 0, 0)`

which returns the error: "In order to reference traces by row and column, you must first use plotly.tools.make_subplots to create the figure with a subplot grid."

Here is my full code with both of the methods mentioned above, commented out.

```
import pprint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.tools as tls
import plotly.graph_objs as go

x =  np.linspace(np.pi, 3*np.pi, 1000)
sinx = np.sin(x)
logx = np.log(x)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,6))
ax.plot(x, logx)
ax.set_title('Two Curves')


plotly_fig = tls.mpl_to_plotly(fig)`
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)`
pp.pprint(plotly_fig)`

plotly_fig['data'].append( dict(x=x, y=logx, type='scatter', mode='lines') )

#plotly_fig.update(data=dict(x=x, y=logx, type='scatter', mode='lines'))

#plotly_fig.add_scatter(name= "test", mode='lines', xaxis='x', yaxis='y',x=x.tolist(), y=sinx.tolist(), line= {'color': 'rgba (31, 119, 180, 1)', 'dash': 'solid', 'width': 1.5})

#new_trace = dict(type='scatter', x=x, y=sinx, mode='lines', line= {'color': 'rgba (31, 119, 180, 1)', 'dash': 'solid', 'width': 1.5})
    #plotly_fig.append_trace(new_trace, 0, 0)

pp.pprint(plotly_fig)

py.plot(plotly_fig, filename='test.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the example code you’re using has become deprecated since plotly 3.0 has switched to representing Figure data as a tuple instead of a list. Because tuples are immutable, you received the error you described.

See docs: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/migration-guide.md#migration-to-version-3

So, change the line

```
plotly_fig['data'].append( dict(x=x, y=logx, type='scatter', mode='lines') )
```

to:

```
plotly_fig.add_trace(dict(x=x, y=logx, type='scatter', mode='lines'))
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to add in the trace to the figure, when I print the figure I see the new trace. However, when I plot the figure again with `py.plot(plotly_fig, filename='sine-and-logarithmic-plot.html')`, the output is the same as before. The new trace still doesn't show up.